# Continuous $\sum_1^\infty u_n(x)$ converge uniformly to F(x). $\lim_{x\to\infty}u_n(x)=b_n<\infty$. Then $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=\sum_1^\infty b_n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\sum_1^\infty u_n(x)$ be a series of continuous functions, and converge to $F(x)$, uniformly for all $x$ with $c\leq x< \infty$. Let $\lim_{x\to\infty}u_n(x)=b_n<\infty$ for $n=1, 2\dots$. Then $\sum_1^\infty b_n$ converges, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=\sum_1^\infty b_n$

Proof in the books:
Setting $x=1/t$, we obtain a series of functions which converges uniformly for $0<t\leq c$. Since $\lim_{t\to 0}u_n{1/t}=b_n$, we can define the terms so as to be continuous at $t=0$. Applying the theorem, the series is uniformly convergent for $0\leq t\leq a$, and we can evaluate $\lim_{t\to 0}F(1/t)=\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)$ termwise.

The theorem the proof used is:
Let E be the closure of an open set. Let $\{f_n\}$ converge uniformly in the interior of $E$. Suppose that each function $f_n$ is continuous on $E$. Then $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly convergent on $E$.

My question is whether the continuous of $u_n$ is relevant in the statement? If it only assumes $\sum_1^n u_n$ uniformly converge to $F$, does the statement still hold?

According to this pose [Proving that I can interchange limit and infinite sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1496182/proving-that-i-can-interchange-limit-and-infinite-sum/1496221#1496221), $\lim_{x \to a} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lim_{x \to a} f_n(x)$, if $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(x)$
converges uniformly.

Since $\sum_1^\infty u_n(x)$ converge to $F$ uniformly, and each $u_n$ that $\lim_{x\to\infty}u_n=b_n<\infty$, then $\sum_1^n \lim_{x\to\infty} u_n=\lim_{x\to\infty} u_1+\dots+\lim_{x\to\infty} u_n=\sum_1^n b_n$.

And since $\sum_1^\infty u_n$ converge to $F(x)$ uniformly, so $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lim_{x \to \infty} u_n(x)$, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=\lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}u_n(x)=\sum_1^\infty bn$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claim 1: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$ converges.

Let $S_{n}(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}u_{k}(x)$. Let $s_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b_{k}$.
We go to show that $(s_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence. Choose $c>0$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $\sum_{n}u_{n}(x)$ converges uniformly
on $[c,\infty)$, there exists $N$ such that $|S_{n}(x)-S_{m}(x)|<\varepsilon$
whenever $N\leq m<n$ and $x\in[c,\infty)$. That is, $\left|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}u_{k}(x)\right|<\varepsilon.$
Letting $x\rightarrow\infty$, we have $|s_{n}-s_{m}|=|\sum_{k=m+1}^{n}b_{k}|\leq\varepsilon$.
Therefore, $(s_{n})$ is a Cauchy sequence and hence $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$
converges.

Claim 2: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$.

We continue to adopt notations we have used in Claim 1. Denote $s=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$.
Fix $m\geq N$ such that $|s_{m}-s|<\varepsilon$. Observe that $S_{m}(x)\rightarrow s_{m}$
as $x\rightarrow\infty$, so there exists $x_{0}>c$ such that $|S_{m}(x)-s_{m}|<\varepsilon$
whenever $x\in[x_{0},\infty)$. Now, let $x\in[x_{0},\infty)$ be
arbitrary. Recall that for any $n>m$, we have $|S_{n}(x)-S_{m}(x)|<\varepsilon$.
Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$, we obtain $|F(x)-S_{m}(x)|\leq\varepsilon$.
Finally, we have estimation:
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & |F(x)-s|\\
 & \leq & |F(x)-S_{m}(x)|+|S_{m}(x)-s_{m}|+|s_{m}-s|\\
 & < & 3\varepsilon.
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}F(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$.

Remark: Continuity of $u_{k}$ or $F$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks! Whether continuity of $u_k$ is irrelevant or not is exactly what I was confused about.

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote is questionable.  You used near the end this:

> if $\sum u_n$ converges uniformly, then $\lim_{x \to \infty} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} u_n(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lim_{x \to \infty} u_n(x)$.

But in fact, that is what the original problem says.  Using it in your proof is probably circular reasoning.

Comment: But a standard 3$\epsilon$ seems to be enough for the statement and the continuous seem to be irrelevant. And it's not circular reasoning, the link has the proof of what I used in the end

Comment: @RRL But even in the original question, standard 3$\epsilon$ proof is almost enough.